# Separating the coordinates for each cluster in DBSCAN using python

Tags: python-3.x

Below scripts gives me the coordinates of each cluster in separate txt files. But i want to edit the content of the file as below

usually the coordinates will get  printed as follows

```
0.64   0.30   0.29
0.27   0.24   0.92
0.34   0.62   0.92
0.05   0.48   0.60
0.26   0.77   0.62
0.15   0.23   0.14
0.35   0.26   0.64
```

But i need it to get printed as Below with all these integers, letters and words for each line.

```
HETATM   1   O  HOH  1 W   0.64   0.30   0.29 1.00  43.38
HETATM   2   O  HOH  2 W   0.27   0.24   0.92 1.00  43.38
HETATM   3   O  HOH  3 W   0.34   0.62   0.92 1.00  43.38
HETATM   4   O  HOH  4 W   0.05   0.48   0.60 1.00  43.38
HETATM   5   O  HOH  5 W   0.15   0.23   0.14 1.00  43.38
HETATM   6   O  HOH  6 W   0.15   0.23   0.14 1.00  43.38
HETATM   7   O  HOH  7 W   0.15   0.23   0.14 1.00  43.38
HETATM   8   O  HOH  8 W   0.15   0.23   0.14 1.00  43.38
HETATM   9   O  HOH  9 W   0.15   0.23   0.14 1.00  43.38
HETATM  10   O  HOH 10 W   0.15   0.23   0.14 1.00  43.38
```

This is like the format of pdb files (.pdb) for proteins

Does anybody knows how to do this?
Below is my script

```py
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(500,3)

db = DBSCAN(eps=0.12, min_samples=1).fit(data)
labels = db.labels_
from collections import Counter
Counter(labels)

from collections import defaultdict

clusters = defaultdict(list)

for i,c in enumerate(db.labels_):
    clusters[c].append(data[i])

for k,v in clusters.items():
    np.savetxt('cluster{}.txt'.format(k), v, delimiter=",", fmt="%1.2f %1.2f %1.2f")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the two `for` loops this way:

```
for i,c in enumerate(db.labels_):
    l = np.concatenate([['HETATM {}'.format(i), 'O  HOH  {} W'.format(i)],data[i],[1.00,  43.38]], axis=0)
    clusters[c].append(l)

for k,v in clusters.items():
    np.savetxt('cluster{}.txt'.format(k), v, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
```

and you get the number of the sample in your dataset, for example:

```
HETATM 2,O  HOH  2 W,0.27035681984544035,0.25141288216432167,0.44097961252275675,1.0,43.38
HETATM 21,O  HOH  21 W,0.2905981520836243,0.2680383230921106,0.47545544921372906,1.0,43.38
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i exactly wanted